# TimeSpan.Parse misinterpreting "12:30". Any idea on how to deal?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, timespan

I have a TimeSpan column, 'ThrEndT' in table 'PostThr' to fill. I want to put in "12:30" to reference to a user 12:30PM. Long story, TimeSpan is better option than DateTime here. (I thought)

```
postThr.ThrEndT = postThr.ThrTime + TimeSpan.Parse("12:30");
```

It spits out "21:30"...I checked it 3 times, and read the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=net-6.0) 3 times. I also tried "12:30:00" with no luck.

I do not know what I am doing wrong nor am I sure how to work around. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You are _adding_ the result (12 hours) to `ThrTime` which is 9 hours, so 21 hours is correct.

Comment: Note that `TimeSpan` should be used to indicate a _duration_, not a _point in time_. It looks like you're trying to use it to indicate a time only with no date component, which may cause problems. I would just include the date component (`ThrDate`?) in your begin and end time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like your code is doing what you want it to.  First you assign `9:00` to `ThrTime`, and then you add that value to `12:30` and assign that to `ThrEndT`, thus getting `21:30`.  That seems right to me.